# Goodman Furnace igniter glows but doesn't ignite

Tags: hvac, heating, furnace, safety

Specs: Goodman Model GDS80703, over 10 years old, Control board replaced 2 years ago

2 months ago, it just started glowing and not igniting, and after doing some basic troubleshooting (Reboot, clean filters, reset thermostat) the problem wasn't solved

As there was sufficient voltage to the gas valve, I was advised by a tech over the phone to replace the gas valve, and did so, It fired up about three times, and each time it didn't reach the temperature desired

Now, we're back at square one, and so we come to you, the people of the internet, for help.

Comment: Did it keep burning without reaching temp, or did the burner cut out prematurely?  Also, what did you use for a replacement gas valve?

Comment: Is the gas valve opening?  Is gas coming out of the orifice(s)? Did you take a close look at the old valve, to see if it was clogged up?  Do you have other gas fired appliances? If so, are those appliances working normally?  Is the gas pressure sufficient?

Comment: Along the lines of the valve being plugged (this can happen with water and or oil in the lines). Is there a "drip leg" prior to the valve. A drip leg is a T in the pipe with a short leg that is capped. This leg catches the contamination before it can get into the valve. 1 drop of water can cause problems in a gas valve because the pressure is so low. If you have a drip leg turn the gas off and remove the cap, it may be full of liquid and residual gas pressure. If you don't have a drip leg check the valve for moisture as this could be the cause of your problem if so install a drip leg.

Answer (score 1):

If you follow the (3) wires from gas valve, two end up on the control board and one goes to a limit switch on the blower. This limit switch was burnt out on my furnace. It's a relatively inexpensive part to replace. Good luck.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.

Answer (score 0):

Swap the nozzle next to the igniter for a different one. Mine used to bang when it lit or not at all light and now it lights quietly every time. Nozzle must have been made just a little different or something. The way it spreads the gas over the is igniter changed and now it’s good

Answer (score -1):

use a new hot surface ignitor ----goodman only----no universal they dont line up

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. We prefer answers that are more than one sentence; would you add a bit of supporting info? Thanks.